# Pass link back to notice in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app I want to pass back link to the notice from the controller.

e.g.

```
redirect_to permalinks_path, :notice => "Permalinks updated! You will want to update the #{link_to 'Site map', sitemap_path} too!"
```

However I get an error:

```
undefined method `link_to' for #<SettingsController:0x007fda280480f8>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [`view_context`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Rendering.html#method-i-view_context):

```
redirect_to(
  permalinks_path,
  :notice => "Permalinks updated! You will want to update the #{view_context.link_to 'Site map', sitemap_path} too!"
)
```

You might also want to add `.html_safe` to the string.

Comment: It treats the second # as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `link_to` method via `view_context`. Do this

```
redirect_to permalinks_path, :notice => "Permalinks updated! You will want to update the #{view_context.link_to('Site map', sitemap_path)} too!"
```

Hope that helps!